# Setting random color for each face in THREEjs results in black object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to render a geometry with each face colored by a random color.

I iterate through `geometry.faces` and set a random color for each face. Upon that I create a new material which is added to the mesh. It seems to me that I've set all the necessary flags, but still my object appears pitch black in the scene.

The scene contains two directional lights, as well as ambient light. In case I use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` the object also appears black, but has some reflections from directional light.

Here is the code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( object );

for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {

    var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
    face.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
}

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
mesh.dynamic = true;
mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

scene.add( mesh );
```

I am using the latest version of three.js: r84

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: It should be `fromBufferGeometry( object.geometry )`.

Comment: Are you sure? It does work this way now. I am asking since I am only new to Three.js. Is this working by accident? What is the difference?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I did, it doesn't work.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

    at Geometry.fromBufferGeometry (three.js:12636)

    at 3DViewer.js:57

    at STLLoader.js:51

    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:29269)`

Comment: You must pass in a `THREE.BufferGeometry` to `Geometry.fromBufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "in  a `THREE.BufferGeometry`"? what do you mean by _in_?

Comment: The argument to `Geometry.fromBufferGeometry()` must be an instance of `THREE.BufferGeometry`. Is the variable you call `object` an instance of `THREE.BufferGeometry`?

Answer (score 3):

Huh! I got it!
We can't just assign color to a face, but we need to assign it to each vertex. Yes, then we have interpolation, which is not really something I want, but at least we can see colors. In case someone knows how to assign color for the face directly without interpolation, I'd be grateful for advice!

This is the new version of the code, just adapt the `for` loop:

```
var faceIndices = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    var face  = geometry.faces[ i ];
    for( var j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
        color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
        face.vertexColors[ j ] = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is a [Multimaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MultiMaterial), with each material within it, (probably a MeshBasicMaterial), assigned a color.

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
function addStar() {
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24)
  const color = THREE.MathUtils.randInt(0, 0xffffff)
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: color})
  const star = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  const [x, y, z] = Array(3).fill().map(() =>THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(100))
  star.position.set(x, y, z)
  scene.add(star) 
}

Array(200).fill().forEach(addStar)
```

}